# What methods SPA apps use to adapt different views for different user roles?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, twig, single-page-application, vue-component

I am developing a kind of CRM. System has 6 base user roles. On the front-end I am using VueJS + Twig (you will understand later why I call it "front-end") and on the back-end - Symfony.

Each module (Project, Lists, Goals etc) has its controller + views (*.html.twig). Each view consists of HTML-blocks connected to Vue instance in the same view (template).

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div id="vuecontainer">...</div>
       <script>
          let vm = new Vue({
             ...
             el: '#vuecontainer',
             ...
          });
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The same view should be displayed differently for all 3 (just an example) roles and not displayed at all for the rest of the roles.

**The question is: what methods SPA apps use to adapt different views for different roles - are there any known pseudo-standard methods with config files for each role? are there any methods with components structuring in a flexible way?**

Currently what I am on - using `if`-s on a Twig-side in a Vue-component.

Similar to:

```
{% if me.role.id in [...] %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

... but that **is** a pain now, when views and interfaces have complex structure and consist from multiple components (fields) where each component has different set of options available for each role.

Before unification (one view - 6 roles) I was using 6 views = 6 roles, but that was also a hell of a pain supporting all the views and components... inheritance, `if`'s and Twig `extends` directives.

Comment: I would strongly advice to completely switch to Vue and get rid of Twig. There is no standard methodology - it depends on your preference. E.g. you may have a single Vue template which contains many `v-if` to accommodate the differences between each role. Or, you may have separate Vue templates for the same component - one template per user role. One of these 2 approaches will be more tedious or more complex in your case - so you will choose the other one. But only you can make this decision - not anyone else.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, eh, I am currently moving from Twig+Symfony to VueJS + REST API (Symfony). `v-if` and different components - it's not the new story. I want to know if there are methods which I am missing... :)

Comment: Well, another option is to use dynamic components - like `<component :is="depending_on_current_user_role"/>`

Comment: @IVOGELOV, hmmm... can you guide me to any good tutorial about `is` directive?

Comment: https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-components/   ;   https://vegibit.com/vuejs-dynamic-components/   ;   http://patrickwho.me/dynamic-components/